# Sharing Controller with a Visualforce Page and Visualforce Email Template

Tags: email, controller, custom, visualforce

I have a Visualforce page with a custom controller that presents sales data in a simple table.  The users would now like to email that data.  So I'm trying to leverage the same controller for both the visualforce page and the email template but I cannot get the parameters to pass into the controller for the email (at least it doesn't appear to be passing in).

This is my **Controller**.  I have a controller for the Visualforce Page that works perfectly fine.  Then I added a second controller for the email component.  The email piece works perfectly too if I hardcode the accountId.  But if I try to pass it in via the email template, it appears to be null as my select statement returns no rows.  What am I doing wrong:

```
public with sharing class SalesReportExtension {
private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
public list<tableRow> dollarTable {get; set;}
public list<tableRow> unitTable {get; set;} 
// set First of Year and Prior Month End dates and table header labels
public date foy {get; set;}
public date pme {get; set;}
public string foyLabel {get; set;}
public string oneAgoLabel {get; set;}
public string oneAgoPLabel {get; set;}
public string twoAgoLabel {get; set;}
public string twoAgoPLabel {get; set;}
// set up account and ship to/sold to variables
public Account a {get;set;}
public string accountId {get;set;}
public string accountName {get;set;}        // display at top of page
public set<string> accountIds = new set<string>();      // used to query records
public list<Account> accountNames {get;set;}
public string selectedFilter {get;set;}
public list<selectOption> filterOptions {get; set;}
public string selectedTimeframe {get;set;}
public list<selectOption> timeframeOptions {get; set;}


public SalesReportExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {  // used for the visualforce page
    accountId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
    system.debug('------------------------- on screen version');
    system.debug('------------------------- accountId: ' + accountId);

    accountIds.add(accountId);
    a = [SELECT Id, Name, Ship_To_SAP_ID__c, Sold_To_SAP_ID__c, ShippingCity, ShippingState FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds];
    accountNames = new list<Account>{a};
    accountName = a.Name;

    // setup picklist values
    filterOptions = selectOptions();
    selectedFilter = 'ShipTo';
    timeframeOptions = timeframeOptions();
    selectedTimeframe = 'YTD';
    dollarTable = getDollarTable();
}

public SalesReportExtension() {  // used for the email template
        accountId = '001i000000AbyAI';
        //accountId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('p3_lkid');
        accountIds.add(accountId);
        a = [SELECT Id, Name, Ship_To_SAP_ID__c, Sold_To_SAP_ID__c, ShippingCity, ShippingState FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds];
        system.debug('------------------------- a: ' + a);
        accountNames = new list<Account>{a};
        accountName = a.Name;
        selectedFilter = 'ShipTo';
        selectedTimeframe = 'YTD';
    } 

public list<tableRow> getDollarTable() {...
```

My **component** (SalesReport) is below.  Interestingly enough the {!aId} and {!accountId} both are correctly returned to the page.  Those line were added for troubleshooting only.

```
<apex:component controller="SalesReportExtension" access="global">
<apex:attribute name="value" description="the Account Id"
              type="String" required="required" assignTo="{!accountId}"/>

<p>
Value = {!value}<br/>
accountId = {!accountId}<br/>
</p>

<apex:dataTable value="{!dollarTable}" var="dt" cellpadding="10" border="1" style="width:700px">
                <apex:column headerValue="Material" style="width:200px; text-align:left;">
                    {!dt.label}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!foyLabel}" style="text-align:right">
                    <apex:outputText value="${0, number, #,##0.00}">
                    <apex:param value="{!dt.Col1}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!oneAgoLabel}" style="text-align:right">
                    <apex:outputText value="${0, number, #,##0.00}">
                    <apex:param value="{!dt.Col2}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!oneAgoPLabel}" style="text-align:right">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, #,##0}%">
                    <apex:param value="{!dt.Col3}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!twoAgoLabel}" style="text-align:right">
                    <apex:outputText value="${0, number, #,##0.00}">
                    <apex:param value="{!dt.Col4}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!twoAgoPLabel}" style="text-align:right">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, #,##0}%">
                    <apex:param value="{!dt.Col5}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

And here is my **email template**:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Sales Report" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Account">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <p>Below is the sales data you requested:</p>
    <c:SalesReport value="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>
    <p>Hope this helps with {!relatedTo.Name}.  If you have any questions just let me know.</p>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

This is my the top half of my **Visualforce page** (this works perfectly).  The command button is the last line of this code snippet.

```
        <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Filter by:" id="filter" columns="4" >
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedFilter}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!filterOptions}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"
                                action="{!filterChanged}"
                                rerender="dataDollarTable,dataUnitTable,accountTable"
                                status="queryStatus"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedTimeframe}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!timeframeOptions}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"
                                action="{!filterChanged}"
                                rerender="dataDollarTable,dataUnitTable,accountTable"
                                status="queryStatus"/>
            </apex:selectList>

            <apex:commandButton value="Email Report" action="{!sendEmail}" id="emailButton"/>
```

Updated comments:  It does seem like I might be past getting the variable passed in as my but I can't tell because a Debug log doesn't seem to generate but I'm assuming the fact that I can display the Value and accountId that I am correctly passing them.  However, my table of data isn't building yet.

Here's a picture of the visualforce page results (which has always worked):

[image]

Here's a picture of the send email template results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues here:

1. Constructor `public SalesReportExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)` will never be called since you stated this is a custom controller (although I'm not so sure about this given your assertion that the VF page works fine).
2. When used in a VF Component, the constructor `public SalesReportExtension()` is called before the setter for the component's `assignTo="{!accountId}"`

Hence, the SOQL select statement in the constructor `public SalesReportExtension()` will not have a value for `accountId` as the list `accountIds` has only a single null element.

A handy reference is the [VF Developer's Guide Order of Execution](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_controller_lifecycle_example.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fpages_controller_lifecycle_example.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

> Update

What triggers the email template to be rendered?  Is it a workflow/approval process w/ email alert? if yes - then the record being triggered will implicitly be bound to `relatedToType`.

I believe that sending an email from 'Send and Email' button on the Account's related lists will also implicitly bind the account to `relatedToType`.

If using apex to send the email via some controller action or webservice, then the value of `setWhatid(..)` does the binding.

When you test/preview in the Email template editor, you have to provide an Account in the popup dialog - this also does the binding.

Comment: So I get what you're saying but how do I fix it so I can get the variable set before that call.  I'm looking through the order of execution help but I'm honestly not seeing (or more likely, understanding) the fix.

Comment: i made an update

Comment: I have a visualforce page that displays a table of sales data.  At the top of that page is a custom button to Send Email.  That opens the send email form with a visualforce template with the component.  So basically I need to email the render the same table of sales data but do it within an email.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: ah - Pls update your post with the URL used in the custom button plus what the Send Email page looks like when populated

Comment: I updated the post last night @crop1645.  I really do appreciate your help.  I thought this would be a fairly simple request from my client but it's proving to be just far enough outside my skill set to make me stumble. :)

Comment: looks like you are close - your current issue appears to be `getDollarTable()` which is returning an empty list. This code was not included. Note that if action `sendEmail` does a redirect to the send an email page, any variables in the `SalesReportExtension` object as of action `sendEmail` will be lost and not reinitiated until the email template's VF component's controller constructor is started.  There is an argument for restructuring into two controllers - (1) for VF page, (2) for component -and a shared class that provides the data needed to render the table in both VF page and component

Comment: Thanks for your help with this crop1645.  I was finally able to get it to work.  I'm not entirely sure what I did to fix it but one thing that seemed to help was on my visualforce email template, I switched from embedding the component to just attaching it as a PDF.  Then i switched the email to using plaintext so the user could edit the email prior to sending.  That was the only big change I think I made.  My guess is that changed the order of execution enough to allow it to work but idk.  Anyway, I wanted to thank you for your guidance.